# Combine data per day and per hour

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I have wind direction data to combine per day and per hour.
[image]

```vb
Sub test()
    Dim arr, i&, d As Object, key, x, temp&, str$, res, m&
    Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    arr = Range("A1").CurrentRegion 'CurrentRegion是arr = Range("A1:C3320")

    For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
        If Not d.exists(arr(i, 1)) Then Set d(arr(i, 1)) = CreateObject("Scripting.dictionary")
        If arr(i, 3) <> "" Then d(arr(i, 1))(arr(i, 3)) = d(arr(i, 1))(arr(i, 3)) + 1
    Next
    ReDim res(1 To d.Count + 1, 1 To 2): m = 1
    res(1, 1) = "Date & Time": res(1, 2) = "Prevailing Wind Direction"
    For Each key In d
        temp = 0: str = ""
        m = m + 1
        For Each x In d(key)
           If d(key)(x) > temp Then
            temp = d(key)(x): str = x
           ElseIf d(key)(x) = temp Then
            str = str & "/" & x
           End If
        Next
        res(m, 1) = Format(key, "YYYY/MM/DD"): res(m, 2) = str
    Next
    With Range("i1").Resize(m, 2)
        .CurrentRegion.ClearContents
        .NumberFormatLocal = "@"
        .Value = res
    End With
End Sub
```

Why can I not combine data and hour as dictionary key and wind direction as item?

Comment: Could you explain the logic in more detail with more examples e.g. what happened to `NNE` and `N` at 4-5 am or to `N` at 6-7 am? Also, share the code you have tried so we can see the cell addresses and worksheet names etc.

Comment: What do you want to appear for example in the 1st to 4th hour?

Answer (score 1):

### Transform Data

```
Sub TransformData()
    
    Const SRC_FIRST_CELL As String = "A1"
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL As String = "I1"
    Const DATE_COL As Long = 1
    Const HOUR_COL As Long = 2
    Const WIND_COL As Long = 3
    Const DH_DELIMITER As String = "|!|"
    Const WIND_DELIMITER As String = "/"
    Const COLUMNS_COUNT As Long = 3 ' fixed
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = ws.Range(SRC_FIRST_CELL).CurrentRegion
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count
    
    Dim dData(): dData = srg.Columns(DATE_COL).Value
    Dim hData(): hData = srg.Columns(HOUR_COL).Value
    Dim wData(): wData = srg.Columns(WIND_COL).Value
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim r As Long, dString As String, wString As String
    
    For r = 2 To srCount
        dString = dData(r, 1) & DH_DELIMITER & hData(r, 1)
        If Not dict.Exists(dString) Then
            Set dict(dString) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        End If
        wString = wData(r, 1)
        dict(dString)(wString) = dict(dString)(wString) + 1
    Next r
    
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = dict.Count + 1
    
    Dim Data(): ReDim Data(1 To drCount, 1 To COLUMNS_COUNT)
    Dim dLen As Long: dLen = Len(DH_DELIMITER)
    
    Data(1, 1) = dData(1, 1)
    Data(1, 2) = hData(1, 1)
    Data(1, 3) = wData(1, 1)
    r = 1
    wString = ""
    
    Dim oKey, iKey, dPos As Long, wMax As Long
    
    For Each oKey In dict.Keys
        r = r + 1
        dPos = InStr(oKey, DH_DELIMITER) - 1
        Data(r, 1) = CDate(Left(oKey, dPos))
        Data(r, 2) = CLng(Right(oKey, Len(oKey) - dPos - dLen))
        For Each iKey In dict(oKey).Keys
            'Debug.Print r, oKey, iKey, dict(oKey)(iKey)
            If dict(oKey)(iKey) > wMax Then
                wString = iKey
                wMax = dict(oKey)(iKey)
            ElseIf dict(oKey)(iKey) = wMax Then
                wString = wString & WIND_DELIMITER & iKey
            End If
        Next iKey
        Data(r, 3) = wString
        'Debug.Print Data(r, 1), Data(r, 2), Data(r, 3)
        wMax = 0
        wString = ""
    Next oKey
    
    With ws.Range(DST_FIRST_CELL).Resize(drCount, COLUMNS_COUNT)
        .CurrentRegion.ClearContents
        .Value = Data
    End With
    
    MsgBox "Data transformed.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. data run perfectly. I try to read code for self learning.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `UNIQUE`, `FILTER` and `TEXTJOIN`.
e.g.

1. First you UNIQUE the hours (extend this to dates)

```
=UNIQUE(A2:A9)
```

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y15pY.png)

2. Then you, find the UNIQUE directions for each hour, UNIQUE them and lastly `TEXTJOIN` them.

```
=TEXTJOIN("/",TRUE,UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B9,A2:A9=D2)))
```

[Final Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kf8DN.png)

[Overall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nz5ev.png)

Comment: Sorry. I need VBA object dictionary. but Thanks a lot for your answer